# Assure an audio device is connected

Tags: c#, windows, audio, bluetooth

I have some Bluetooth audio devices paired to my system. These can sometimes be disconnected. If I go into the Sound control panel, look for the device in the Playback devices list, and right click&select "connect", then everything works again.

**How do I do that programmatically in C#?**

I've tried 32feet and NAudio already, but the State property of their BluetoothDevice and MMDevice classes is read-only.

In a perfect world, I would find a function like this:

```
BluetoothConnector.Connect("MyBluetoothDevice");
```

Comment: There are 2 solutions (actually one, but in different ways). First small remark: unfortunately windows does not provide easy method to connect to audio device from the applications. But you can use some tricks. You need to uninstall drivers for your paired device and install them again. For both operations you have to call BluetoothSetServiceState() function from Win Bluetooth API. The other way to do the same is to use [Bluetooth Framework](https://www.btframework.com/bluetoothframework.htm) that provides 2 methods InstallDevice and UninstallDevice.

Comment: Is that the equivalent to unpair them and pair them again?

Comment: Yes and No. Yes if you do it through Bluetooth Add Device UI and No when you unpair and pair again using Bluetooth API (Windows does not iunstall drivers for supported services in this case). Acutally when you unpair device (eather way) windows also deletes installed drivers. However, when you pair with device using UI (Add Device) Windows actually does 2 operations: pairing and then (if success) installs drivers for supported services.

Comment: I see... I guess I need to figure out how to call APIs. I'ver been avoiding them long enough haha Thanks Mike